# "Enable remote error" in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

When I compile a report in SSRS, an common error occurred as shown.
I may probably "Enable remote error" in Reporting Services server to fix the report connection in SSRS. 
But:
What is the impact of doing that? Will it affect existing production jobs?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Follow below procedure to enable remote error in SSRS

1) Open SQL Server Management studio and log in with reporting services as the service type.

[image]

2) right click on the instance and go to properties so here attach an image as the popup is shown after goto **Advanced** tab here you can find **EnableRemoteError** in **Security** tree.

[image]

After enabling remote error you can figure out actual error thrown by the database.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Also note that this affects all reporting environments on that server, if you wish to update individual environments running on the same server, see the `ConfigurationInfo` (where [Name] = 'EnableRemoteErrors') table in the environment's databases

Comment: The EnableRemoteError in the Security tree isn't visible to me. Why?

Answer (score 10):

1. Connect to the database engine in SSMS and navigate to the ReportServer database.
2. Query the ConfigurationInfo table to get familiar with it.  Issue the following query:

   USE ReportServer

   GO

   UPDATE ConfigurationInfo
   SET Value = 'True'
   WHERE Name = 'EnableRemoteErrors'
3. Restart Reporting Services on the server:
   Click Start > Administrative Tools > Services to open the Services management console. Right-click the SQL Server Reporting Services ([InstanceName]) 
   service, and then click Restart.

Comment: Minor note - restart the Reporting Services services on the server to enable this...